# RDLC (SSRS) Keep group togeather

Tags: .net, reporting-services, report, rdlc, ssrs-grouping

I am creating a report that needs to display data in two columns. It has only one DataSet from an object data source. Also data must be grouped by ID field in that DataSet. That was the easy part and the report basically looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that I need to keep the group together so that it does not break into two columns but to look like this:

[image]

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can try using KeepTogether property of your Group but I don't know if it works with columns.

Comment: At first I have set that but with no success. Now that you've mentioned it I have rechecked the KeepTogeather property, it was true on group but not on group details, setting it to true on group details solved it. 
Thanks!